# Does jQuery ajaxSetup method not work with $.get or $.post?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Does the jQuery `$.ajaxSetup` method not respect the `data` field in the options hash when `$.post` or `$.get` is called?

For example, I might have this code:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ data: { persist: true } });
```

Then, to send a POST request, I would call this:

```
$.post("/create/something", { name: "foo" });
```

I was expecting the actual POST data to look like this:

```
{
  persist: true,
  name: "foo"
}
```

but the only data sent by `$.post` is `{ name: "foo" }`. Is there any way to get the expected behavior? I'm using jQuery 1.4.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$.ajaxSetup()` sets defaults for your ajax requests.  Any options you set in the request method will override these defaults, not merge them.  You're actually overriding

```
{ persist: true }
```

with

```
{ name: "foo" }
```

---

This no longer appears to be the case — [a ticket on the jQuery tracker](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/3387) suggests that this was added in a version update and jQuery now merges the objects instead of replacing the default (thanks @Quincy).

Comment: Although this question is a year old, the merge is working now. Just comment here in case of anyone reading this. @see http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/3387

Comment: I've tried merging a post parameter in ajaxSetup with data using serializeArray but this overrides the parameter defined in axaxSetup

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21501224/define-global-ajax-post-param-and-merge-with-different-requests

Answer (score 0):

As [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) says `data` option is converted to query string and appended to the URL for GET requests.

Comment: I think the documentation is unclear here.  For a POST request, `data` should be converted to a query string and sent via the POST body.